# Error in LeNet on MNIST example

Tags: bash, caffe

I followed the guidance under the Training LeNet on MNIST with Caffe but I've got a error when creating lmdb..

```
$ ./examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh
Creating lmdb...
F:/program files/caffe/build/examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.exe:
 error while loading shared libraries: boost_python-vc140-mt-1_61.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm using GIT Bash for run the shell script,
so what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the linker/loader does not have access to that Python BOOST library.  Did you run the scripts needed to set your environment variables?  I suspect that there's a missing path in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

As a stop-gap, you can locate the missing file with

```
find / -name boost_python-vc140-mt-1_61.dll
```

... and then manually add that path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  The problem is that you'll hit thesefiles/caffe/build/examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.exe one at a time until you get them all.

You can also try

```
ldd files/caffe/build/examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.exe
```

... and see what you might be missing.

Comment: I followed the instruction `ldd files/caffe/build/examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.exe` that you mentioned but it does not seem that something is missing.. also i set path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH by this command `export LD_LIBARAY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/f/program files/caffe/build/libraries/lib/boost_python-vc140-mt-1_61.dll` but the error still occur,i'm using windows so sorry i don't have a big background in linux and i don't know if i made a mistake in adding the path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH! is there something wrong ?

Comment: When you set the library path, you need only the *path* -- the directory containing the file(s) you want.  Remove the file name itself, and try again with just the directory name, ending with **/lib/**.